# PHP get the date of this weeks monday

Tags: php, date

Any way to take a date like this `2013-05-29` in PHP and get the date (in the same format) of that weeks monday? So the output would be like this: `2013-05-27`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
date('Y-m-d', strtotime('last sunday +1 day', strtotime('2013-05-29')));
```

`last sunday +1 day` because `last monday` would return the Monday of the *previous* week if $timestamp actually *was* a Monday already.

And parsing of the original date value `2013-05-29` in a second step because all together as one argument does not work well (mixing of absolute and relative date values is something strtotime does not like very much).